# Force update `this.props.location.search` on React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a function to construct a query string like this:

```
search = (params) => {
    for (let key in params) {
        if (params[key] === '') delete params[key];
    }
    params = CaseConverter.camelCaseToSnackCase(params);
    let paramString = queryString.stringify(params);
    paramString = '?' + paramString;
    this.props.history.push(paramString);
    this.callAPI();
}
```

Here is the callAPI function:

```
callAPI = () => {
    get('/endpoint' + this.props.location.search).then(response => {});
}
```

However, `this.props.location.search` would not be updated on the first call. I always have to call `search` twice to get what I wanted. Anybody knows a solution to this?

Note: I'm using `react`, `react-router-dom` v4, `query-string`

Answer (score 0):

You'll see the updated props only in the next rerender. Why not pass the query directly to the `callAPI` function like this:

```
search = (params) => {
    for (let key in params) {
        if (params[key] === '') delete params[key];
    }
    params = CaseConverter.camelCaseToSnackCase(params);
    let paramString = queryString.stringify(params);
    paramString = '?' + paramString;
    this.props.history.push(paramString);
    this.callAPI(paramString);
}

callAPI = (q) => {
    get('/endpoint' + q).then(response => {});
}
```

Comment: I have other function that can construct the query parameters (pagination), so I want to find a way to keep in sync with the parameters in the URL. I can achieve this with `ng-model` in Angular, but I still struggle in React